# Deleting a line and lines after it

Tags: sed

I'm trying editing some text file using sed. In the text file there are two lines starting with a `string`. I want to delete only the first one and say 3 lines after it. How can I do that with sed?

input:

```
string
line1
line2
line3
####
other lines
####
string
line4
line5
line6
```

output:

```
###
other lines
###
string
line4
line5
line6
```

I've tried `sed '/string/,+3d'` but it deletes both `string`s and 3 line after them which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat remlines.txt
sometext1
sometext2
sometext3
string
line1
line2
line3
####
other lines
####
string
line4
line5
line6
```

Getting line number for the first `string` occurance

```
$ startln=$(grep -nrm 1 "string" remlines.txt | cut -d : -f 1)
```

Using `sed` to remove lines range starting from `string` and ending by `string's line number + 3)`

```
$ sed "$(($startln)),$(($startln+3))d" remlines.txt > newremlines.txt


$ cat newremlines.txt
sometext1
sometext2
sometext3
####
other lines
####
string
line4
line5
line6
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is the one I think I should go with.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't absolutely need to use `sed`, here are some alternatives:

```
$ awk '{ if(/string/ && !a){a=1;getline;getline;getline;getline} print}' file
####
other lines
####
string
line4
line5
line6
```

Or Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/string/ && !$a){$a=1;readline;readline;readline; next} print' file
####
other lines
####
string
line4
line5
line6
```

Perl has the advantage that it has the same `-i` option as `sed` (in fact, the option originated in Perl and was copied to `sed`) for in-place editing:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'if(/string/ && !$a){$a=1;readline;readline;readline; next} print' file
```

Comment: also maybe `ed`? e.g. `printf '%s\n' '/string/;+3d' ',p' | ed -s input`

Comment: @steeldriver I am ashamed to admit I don't know the first thing about `ed`. I am sure it will work as advertised but I have no idea. I was kind of expecting you to come up with some nifty `sed` trick too, do you think it's actually not possible in sed?

Comment: tbh I only know just about enough to be dangerous myself ;)

Comment: Thank you! It's working although I didn't have tested the perl version but awk is fine. Thanks